# How to resolve deprecated and error issues with Flutter widgets and properties?

Tags: flutter, flutter-dependencies

I am facing a problem with flutter, I am not able to use many things,
like headline1 or headline2 etc, they all are striked out and say they are deprecated.

I can't use accentcolor it throws an error, and I can't use "with preferred size widget".

What should I do to make them work?

Comment: https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/TextTheme/headline1.html

Answer (score 0):

You should take a look at the document https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/TextTheme/headline1.html

> @Deprecated('Use displayLarge instead. ' 'This feature was deprecated after v3.1.0-0.0.pre.')

As the document said you can use displayLarge instead of headline1

With the accentColor you can check this document https://docs.flutter.dev/release/breaking-changes/theme-data-accent-properties

The migration guide've been already listed.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).